# Joomla 3.4 Radiance not working on mobile phone

Tags: joomla-3.x, gantry, mobile-web-design

I recently updated from Joomla 3.3.2 to Joomla 3.4, and also updated the template Radiance to v1.10, but Pages doesn't look right on iphone and Android. How can I make the site mobile friendly?

Comment: Could you provide us with some additional information? Like what Radiance is (maybe a hyperlink). Did you try to debug? Maybe you could enable Joomla's debug mode for your site and see what you get. You could also try to inspect your javascript using Firebug.

Comment: You're going to need to provide much more than this. A link to your site would be a good place to start

Comment: @mattosmat yes i turn on Error Reporting ,but doesn't show any error.

Comment: @Lodder. I'm working on local server,so i can't provide the link

Comment: How do you expect us to help then? Also, you're trying to access your localhost from your phone?

Comment: Yes,if i turn on the Desktop request the page has been display with out responsive.but mobile format is not working

Comment: You should contact the developer of the template. It's on your localhost, therefore we have no access to it, so we can't preview your issue.

Comment: ok thank let me check with template designer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [RocketTheme](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla-templates/radiance/) and [YooTheme](https://yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2012/radiance/) has a template called *Radiance*, both are from 2011-2012 and are **NOT** responsive. I'm going to assume you're using the RocketTheme template, since the latest version is 1.10.

When RocketTheme started with "mobile friendly" templates, they weren't actually responsive, but included an option to load a customized version of the template for iPhone and Android. This means they somehow detected the device, and styled the page accordingly. A few templates later they began with responsive design.

To see how a responsive website works, it's simply a matter of re-sizing the browser window. With your template, however, in order to test on localhost you have to emulate an iPhone/Android device, and even then I find it rather random if I see the mobile or full version:

[image: Android Mobile view]

[image: iPhone mobile view]

The best way to test your website is to place it on a live server and test with a real phone. Even so, remember that these templates are responsive based on device, not on screen size. Responsive should be design-driven, not device-driven.